# SpringBoot Required request body is missing from browser

Tags: javascript, json, spring-boot, rest

i have a POST request using springboot, everything works fine when i make tests on postman but when i try it from the browser i get this error,

Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Required request body is missing: public org.springframework.

this is my code.

the Service class

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor = {SQLException.class})
    public ResponseEntity<Message> save(Cursos cursos) {
        Optional<Cursos> optionalCursos = cursosRepository.findByTituloCursos(cursos.getTituloCursos());

        if (optionalCursos.isPresent()) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(new Message("la entrada ya existe", null), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(new Message("ok", false, cursosRepository.saveAndFlush(cursos)), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

DTO class

```
public class CursosDTO {

    long id;

    @NotNull
    String tituloCursos;

    @NotNull
    String cuerpocursos;

    public CursosDTO() {
    }

    public CursosDTO(long id, String tituloCursos, String cuerpocursos) {
        this.id = id;
        this.tituloCursos = tituloCursos;
        this.cuerpocursos = cuerpocursos;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTituloCursos() {
        return tituloCursos;
    }

    public void setTituloCursos(String tituloCursos) {
        this.tituloCursos = tituloCursos;
    }

    public String getCuerpocursos() {
        return cuerpocursos;
    }

    public void setCuerpocursos(String cuerpocursos) {
        this.cuerpocursos = cuerpocursos;
    }
}
```

controller class

```
 @PostMapping("/")
    public ResponseEntity<Message> save(@RequestBody CursosDTO cursosDTO) {
        Cursos saveCursos = new Cursos(cursosDTO.getTituloCursos(), cursosDTO.getCuerpocursos());
        return cursosService.save(saveCursos);
    }
```

and this is my JavaScript code

```
fetch(url)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
            console.log(data);
            let dataUpd = {
                tituloCursos: titulo,
                cuerpocursos: contenido
            };
            console.log(JSON.stringify(dataUpd) + " prueba");

            fetch(url, {
                method: "POST",
                BODY: dataUpd,
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                },
            })
                .then((res) => res.json())
                .catch((error) => console.error("error al subir datos: ", error))
                .then((response) => {
                    console.log("Datos subidos: ", response);
                })
        })
```

when i fetch data it brings all the data stored in the db correctly and this is the info that im trying to store

```
{"tituloCursos":"Stack","cuerpocursos":"<p>Overflown</p>"}
```

just in case it is relevant im using edge browser and im trying to store info from a rich text editor using tinymce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably a very simple typo. You capitalized `BODY` in your Post requests js code. It needs to be lowercase: `body`

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#supplying_request_options

Also, you would need to JSON.stringify your Data so your request options for the Post request would look like this:

```
  method: "POST",
  body: JSON.stringify(dataUpd),
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
```

Comment: thanks man you were right on both as soon as i fix the typo another error showed but was the stringify issue